# Dependancy is not satisfiable, trying to install pencil2d

Tags: 16.10, deb, gdebi

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10

I'm trying to install `pencil2d_0.5.4-20130728.1_amd64.deb` and I got this message: `Dependancy is not satisfiable:libgif4 (>=4.1.4)`

Please Help

Comment: do a search with this: `apt search pencil2d` to see if it can be installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has the same version (*0.5.4~git20160910.8850389+dfsg-1* to be correct) on his universe repo but repackaged (Nightly 20160910) and without the `libgif4` dependecy.

[image]

I cleanly installed it on my system with `sudo apt install pencil2d` without problems.